# Stuck Transaction for almost 2 days, have paid fees

Tags: confirmations

Can anybody please help with 1 transaction, its stuck already for 2 days, altho I did pay fees, not sure whats the issue, other payments sent after this has been confirmed already
https://blockchain.info/tx/89e3318664af7dc1e9f7ad7d20708e50c707ed706c7f6eae9a9fcf44af3295d2

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem and was at the mercy of too low of a fee I sent. 
I'd been waiting 36 hours and then tried this: https://www.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/        I have no idea it might be a coincidence but it confirmed within the hour. Could just be coincidence. So I put your transaction in there for ya. let me know if anything changes!!!! :)

Comment: It worked!Thanks for your help. Please let me know your btc adress, so I can send you some bucks for helping out